# Implement Kofax Ascent Capture Database Release Script

Tags: kofax

I am trying to set up a release script to a MySQL database. I have the ODBC connection installed and get the prompts for the table/index information but i'm confused.

I have a table JurorImages, I would like this table populated automatically by the Ascent Capture Release script. It contains 2 fields: JurorID and ImagePath.

On the image we are scanning there is a bar code, this barcode is the JurorID. I would like to have the number from this barcode in the JurorID field and the path of the image to the ImagePath.

I'm stuck on the 'Index' information. Do I have to create a temporary table to put this information into?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks,
leslie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found some information in the KnowledgeBase (QAID#4091) - What are the requirements to use release scripts with ODBC compliant database and how do I configure the tables http://knowledgebase.kofax.com/faqsearch/results.aspx?QAID=4091.

So it appears that you do have to have 2 tables, one with the documentid and path and another with all the other fields you need PLUS the documentID.

So I have set that up:

TableName:  KofaxRelease

Fields:
   DocumentID
   ImagePath

TableName:  JurorImage

Fields:
   JurorID (which comes from the barcode on the document)
   DocumentID

now however every document is rejected and I can't figure out why....anyone tell me where there's a log file or some other way to tell why the document was rejected?

Thanks,
Leslie